# How to edit integer inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The user wants to build a password brute forcer.

The password is only numerical (PIN). He's using a while loop to start at 1, then add a 1, try 2, add a 1, try 3 etc until it gets the right one.

He's having issues adjusting the integer value of the password/pin and getting it going in a loop:

```
def starLite(username, pin):
    out = subprocess.check_output(["bank.exe", username, str(pin)], shell=True)
    out = str(out, 'utf-8')
    out = out.strip()
    return out

output = starLite("timshaw", 1)
print(output)

while (output) == "Wrong Pin":
        print("wrong")
output = starLite("timshaw", int(+ 1))
```

A working 'password cracking machine', he has not been provided with an explanation of what happens when you actually guess the correct value

Comment: 0 is also an integer. So are negative integers. Do you mean "positive integer"? Otherwise your code could loop forever without finding the integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the PIN in a variable so you can increment it each time through the loop.

```
pin = 1
while starLite("timshaw", pin) == "Wrong Pin":
    print("wrong")
    pin += 1
```